# Are vectors and (not necessarily linear) transformations/maps the same thing?

Tags: abstract-algebra, transformation

As I learn more mathematics, I increasingly notice similarities between concepts that are otherwise identified differently. I only have knowledge of basic linear algebra, but it seems to me that a vector and a transformation/map are the same thing?

If I have the vector $\overrightarrow{r}(x, y) = (xy, x+2, 3)$, then it is mapping from $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$, right?

The parameterisation $\overrightarrow{r}(t) = (t, t^2)$ is mapping from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R^2}$.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

P.S. I'm not entirely sure what to tag this with, but I suspect it falls under the category of abstract algebra. If not, then I would appreciate it if people could kindly edit my question with the appropriate tags.

Comment: vectors and transformation/map are not  same....

Comment: @NoorAslam Ok, care to elaborate? Can you address my specific examples?

Comment: yes but can you explain further 
what is your question?

Comment: @NoorAslam My question was, "Are vectors and (not necessarily linear) transformations/maps the same thing?" I then gave specific examples to demonstrate why It seems to me like they may be the same phenomenon.

Comment: Your $\vec{r}$ is not a vector. For fixed $x, y$, $\vec{r}(x,y)$ is a vector; $\vec{r}$ itself is a function (and in this case, a linear function).

Comment: @Magdiragdag Ok, this makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transformation and map are functions. So in a general sense they are the same. Vectors are not functions.

One may call $\overrightarrow r$ a vector field, which is an old term. In general, a vector field is a map $\mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{m}$. (see Apostol's Calculus II, for instance).

Every element of a vector space is called a vector. For example, a point of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, a vector space, is called a vector for every integer $n \geq 1$.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So are the terms transformation, vector, and map all referring to the same phenomenon?

Comment: @ThePointer, A quick, to-the-point answer is in my revised answer :).

Comment: Thanks, Eric. This makes sense. With respect to Magdiragdag's comment, would the would the $\overrightarrow{r}$ itself be classified as a function rather than a vector?

Comment: @ThePointer, Yes you defined $\overrightarrow r$ as a function!

Comment: "...the vector r(x,y)=(xy,x+2,3)..." is not a single vector, but rather a set of vectors (depending on what x and y happen to be).  And yes, r(x,y) --> (xy,x+2,3) is a vector representation of an R2 --> R3 mapping (transformation).  But the transformation itself (mapping an R2 vector (x,y) onto an R3 vector) is not a "vector".

Comment: Ok, this has been illuminating. My thanks to both of you. I have learned something new today. :)

Answer (score 0):

i am giving you certain example 
that is linear transformation
consider
$$f:R\to R$$
$$f(x)=exp(x)$$
you see that this is linear transformation but there is no vector involve here
so you can conclude that vectors and transformations are not same.....